# Why does Mathematica calculate the same inverse Fourier function for two different functions?

Tags: inverse, fourier-transform

Consider the following function:

$F(\omega )=\frac{2 \sin \left(a \omega ^2\right) \sin (b \omega )}{\omega }=\frac{\cos \left(a \omega ^2-b \omega \right)-\cos \left(a \omega ^2+b \omega \right)}{\omega }$

Mathematica calculates the same inverse Fourier for the two functions in the right-hand side, namely,

$
\mathcal{F}_{\omega }^{-1}\left[\frac{\cos \left(a \omega ^2+b \omega \right)}{\omega }\right](t)=\frac{\log (-i (b+t))-\log (i (b+t))-\log (i t-i b)+\log (i b-i t)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}
$

$
\mathcal{F}_{\omega }^{-1}\left[\frac{\cos \left(a \omega ^2-b \omega \right)}{\omega }\right](t)=\frac{\log (-i (b+t))-\log (i (b+t))-\log (i t-i b)+\log (i b-i t)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}
$

Therefore, Mathematica yields zero value for $\mathcal{F}_{\omega }^{-1}\left[\frac{2 \sin (a \omega ) \sin \left(b \omega ^2\right)}{\omega }\right](t)$, which is incorrect.
How can I solve such problem in Mathematica?

Comment: There is a problem in your question because the Fourier transform of $e^{i\pi t^2}$ is $(-i)^{-1/2}e^{-i\pi\xi^2}$, the FT of $pv(e^{i \pi t^2}/2i\pi t)$ is $\int (-i)^{-1/2}e^{-i \pi \xi^2}d\xi= (-i)^{-1/2}erf(-i \pi \xi^2)/\pi$. What Mathematica computed is the FT of $\frac{\cos \left(a \omega-b \omega \right)-\cos \left(a \omega+b \omega \right)}{\omega }$ and the result it gave has different branches of $\log$.

Comment: The inverse of Fourier transformation is obtained by the command InverseFourierTransform[F[w],w,t] in Mathematica.